# How to show a shaded glow outside a circle in android

Tags: android

How to show a shaded glow blended with the background color when you draw a circle on a canvas in android.

My circle is orange colored and the background is blue. I am trying to show a halo of white color which fades to the background color

Comment: use a BlurMaskFilter?

Comment: Any example ? any link

Comment: google("BlurMaskFilter example")